# Ошибка при настройке LAMP на Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: ubuntu, apache, apache2, tcp, lamp

Установил ***apache2*** через команду

```
sudo apt install apache2
```

затем установил ***php*** используя команду

```
sudo apt install php libapache2-mod-php php-mysql php-xml php-curl php-gd php-zip php-mbstring
```

Затем ***запустил apache2***, захожу на `http://localhost/` а в ответ пишется ошибка

**dial tcp 127.0.0.1:80: connect: connection refused**

Из-за чего такое может быть и как это исправить? Ранее на 18.04 по тойже инструкции настраивал и такой ошибки небыло.

***UPD.1*** - запустил команду `ss -tunap | grep 80` показывает следующие пункты (сначала показывал пунктов 10, после перезагрузки системы и запуска апачи начал показывать три):

```
tcp   LISTEN      0       10              0.0.0.0:8000            0.0.0.0:*                                                                                     
tcp   ESTAB       0       0           192.168.0.2:37956   173.194.221.113:443    users:(("firefox",pid=4946,fd=80))                                             
tcp   LISTEN      0       128                   *:80                    *:*
```

Comment: `ss -tunap | grep 80` ?

Comment: @nobody так, запустил я эту команду, мне вывелся список из 10 элементов, что мне там нужно искать?

Comment: пока достаточно добавить вывод в вопрос

Comment: @nobody добавил

Comment: `curl http://127.0.0.1/` или `curl http://localhost/`

Comment: `sudo ps aux | grep -E 'apac|http|dock'`

Comment: @nobody обе команды выводят html код с [таким содержимым](https://gist.github.com/alexsoin/79e9620bd7c83aff33795dba5ca09cd6)

Comment: Ну, значит у Вас всё нормально с LAMP, поздравляю. А проблема кроется где-то на этапе "... захожу на ...", вот и поищите её (разные браузеры например, или как-то ещё), а потом нам расскажите результат своих изысканий :)

Comment: @nobody я мягко говоря в шоке! :) три вечера мучался с этой ерундой, а сейчас установил chromium и всё сразу заработало, выходит дело было в firefox... фуф... раз 7 точно за это время переустанавливал сервер))) Спасибо большое!

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88690/discussion-between-alexsoin-and-nobody).

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка, в моем случае, выводилась из-за включенного **vpn** дополнения в браузере Firefox, после его отключения все заработало как надо.

Проверить работает ли у вас LAMP сервер можно используя команды которые привел пользователь @nobody выше в комментариях.